# i want to show icon on kendo chart bar javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I am using kendo chart in javascript and i want to show icons on every bar following is diagram that i want to achieve with kendo chart. Below is code that i am using for kendo.

[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frfov.png)

following is javascript code of kendo chart

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
                     title: {
                        // text: "Comparison of Drying Methods",
                     },
                     legend: {
                         position: "bottom",
                         item: {
                             visual: createLegendItem
                         }
                     },
                     seriesDefaults: {
                         type: "column",
                         stack: true,
                         highlight: {
                             toggle: function (e) {
                                 // Don't create a highlight overlay,
                                 // we'll modify the existing visual instead
                                 e.preventDefault();

                                 var visual = e.visual;
                                 var opacity = e.show ? 0.8 : 1;

                                 visual.opacity(opacity);
                             }
                         },
                         visual: function (e) {
                             return createColumn(e.rect, "#0099CC")// e.options.color);
                         }
                     },
                     series: [{
                         data: [Math.round(data.noTreatmentLA * 10) / 10, Math.round(data.afterCoolerLA * 10) / 10, Math.round(data.refrigerantLA * 10) / 10, Math.round(data.membranceLA * 10) / 10, Math.round(data.desiccantLA * 10) / 10] 
                     }],
                     panes: [{
                         clip: false
                     }],
                     valueAxis: [
                        {
                            title: { text: "Water Content" }
                        }
                     ],
                     categoryAxis: {
                         categories: ["Treatment", "Cooler", "Refri", "Membra", "Disi"],
                         majorGridLines: {
                             visible: false
                         },
                         line: {
                             visible: false
                         }

                     }, 
                     tooltip: {
                         visible: true
                     },
                     seriesDefaults: {
                         labels: {
                             visible: true,
                             template:'water'
                         }
                     },
                     seriesClick: onSeriesClick
                 });
```

Comment: Have you found anything in the chart api from kendo ui ?   Your image is really not ideal for a mockup of what you are wanting to convey.  Try to find a better example as well.

Comment: Without more detail it is hard to know exactly what you want. Take a look at series notes: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.notes.icon or using the visual function to draw what you want, e.g.: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/onALe